# Singular Jonsson cardinals

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, large-cardinals

Is the following consistent?

> **$(*)$:** There exists a singular cardinal $\kappa$ such that :
>
> (1) $\kappa$ is a Jonsson cardinal,
>
> (2) $\kappa$ is not a fixed point of the $\aleph-$function, i.e., $\kappa < \aleph_\kappa.$

If we remove the second assumption, then the answer is positive and easy:

**(A):**  Prikry forcing over a measurable cardinal $\kappa,$ turns $\kappa$ into a singular Jonsson cardinal, but $\kappa=\aleph_\kappa$ in such a model.

**(B):** If $κ$ is a singular limit of measurable cardinals, then $κ$ is
Jonsson, but again $\kappa=\aleph_\kappa$ .

Comment: What happens if $\kappa$ is the limit of $\omega$ measurable cardinals, and you collapse them to be $\aleph_{\omega+n}$, or singularize them and collapse them to be $\aleph_{\omega\cdot n}$?

Comment: Maybe the paper "On the consistency strength of "accessible" Jonsson cardinals" of Donder and Koepke will be useful for getting a lower bound. They prove there that the existence of such Jonsson cardinal implies the existence of zero dagger. I think that using the current inner models machinery, one can improve their result and get a Woodin cardinal.

Comment: There is a word missing in the main sentence, so I don't understand what the question is. It looks like you're asking whether the emphasized part is consistent? But what is "well-known" then? I'm confused.

Comment: @YCor My question is if there is a singular cardinal satisfying both (1) and (2). If we remove (2), then we know the answer.

Comment: I think that Dominik Adolf talked about something like this in the recent RIMS meeting in Kyoto, and the consistency strength of such statement is quite high. So just using measurable cardinals is far from enough.